# RabbitMQ send and consume message within one connection

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, producer-consumer

Could I create one connection for listening a queue and sending messages to another exchange ? 
Currently, in case I use one connection for sending, my consumer receives it, but it even is not bound to this exchange.

Maybe, some settings should be changed ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your problem. Are you saying that you send a message to an exchange, and it is received on a queue that has no binding? If so, can you show the configuration of the exchange and queue, and also the code you're using to send the message?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,
you can use the same connection but you have to use two channels.

Read here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html

For example:

```cs
using (var channel = myConnection.CreateModel())
{
    channel.QueueDeclare("hello", false, false, false, null);

    var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
    channel.BasicConsume("", true, consumer);
```

and with the same connection...

```cs
using (var channel = myConnection.CreateModel())
{
    channel.QueueDeclare("hello", false, false, false, null);
    string message = "Hello World!";
    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

    channel.BasicPublish("", "", null, body);
    Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
}
```

Please note:
The c# channel isn't multi-threading so you should create one for thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I realized that you even don't have to use 2 different channels for receiver and consumer. You can use one for both of them.

Comment: you are welcome, and yes you can use the same channel, but be careful the channel in c# ins't multi-thread, read here:
http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.3.0/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.3.0-user-guide.pdf (section"IModel should not be shared between threads" )

There is a big difference between Connection and Channel.

Answer (score 2):

Yea, sure you can go with it.

- In RabbitMq you would like to keep connection (at least one) open as
  long as possible, due to performance impact of opening one each and
  every time, it thread safe in C#.
- On opposite. channel is meant to be opened for each and every thread
  and can't be shared in C# client implementation.

Until you work strictly linear (no parallel processing), you can consume process and publish via same channel (on of course same connection).

**Pay attention** that multiple channels that were opened for one connection can block each other in terms of traffic. Only one channel can send/receive through connection simultaneously. Because of this try organizing connections and channels that will not block each other during simultaneous publish and consume.